# Get-AzureSubscription : Failed to refresh token. AADSTS90002

Tags: powershell, azure

I am getting a strange error when executing a Microsoft Azure powershell command.  After successfully adding my account to the shell via Add-AzureAccount, I am getting a failure when I execute Get-AzureSubscription.  The error message says:

```
Get-AzureSubscription : Failed to refresh token. AADSTS90002: No service namespace named
'[REMOVED GUID FROM QUESTION]'was found in the data store.
Trace ID: [REMOVED GUID FROM QUESTION]
Correlation [REMOVED GUID FROM QUESTION]
Timestamp: 2015-02-15 20:34:14Z: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
```

I have multiple subscriptions against the single account.  It looks like there is a tenant that might be associated to that account locally, but doesn't exists when the REST call is made.  I did delete an Azure AD domain earlier.

Comment: Also happened to me after deleting several AD tenants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the content of the folder **C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Windows Azure Powershell**

After which again run Add-AzureAccount to get the fresh one

Comment: +1 This answer could use a little TLC -- you kind of need to piece together all three answers to this question.  The neccessary steps are: 1) del the contents of $env:appdata\windows azure powershell (or delete the directory).  2. Exit powershell (I found this to be necessary after multiple attempts) 3. Run Add-AzureAccount again.

Answer (score 1):

If following the solution from ***LaPuyaLoca*** the problem does not resolve as it happened in my case, close all the powershell running consoles and just delete the "**Windows Azure Powershell**" folder and run the **Add-AzureAccount** again.

Answer (score 0):

The comment from Wriju is correct except from the fact that you'll need to add the user name folder you are using.

C:\Users\{**{username}**\AppData\Roaming\Windows Azure Powershell

Also If you are trying to search it through file explorer you'll need to turn on show hiden files option